# Identification of dual space

Tags: representation-theory

Let $Q$ be a finite quiver and let $M$ denote the $k$-vector space generated by all arrows. Let $Q^{\ast}$ denote the opposite quiver of $Q$, i.e reverse all arrows. Now let $M^{\ast}$ denote the $k$-vector space generated by all arrows of $Q^{\ast}$. Why can we identify $M^{\ast}$ with $Hom_{k}(M,k)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dimension of $M^\ast$ and $\hom(M, k)$ both equal the number of arrows in $Q$, so to identify them we just have to choose a basis and identify the basis elements.  For $M^\ast$ the basis is the opposite arrows, for $M$ the basis is the arrows and $\hom(M, k)$ then has a corresponding dual basis.  So we just identify an opposite arrow $a^\ast \in M^\ast$ with the basis element in $\hom(M, k)$ which is dual to the basis element $a \in M$.

Comment: As for the map you listed, if that's a definition then I don't see an issue, you can define anything you want.  Is there a reason you don't think it's well defined?

Comment: Yes, it's an isomorphism.